# "Beijing Baidu Netcom Science Technology" recurrent UAC never stops

Tags: windows-10, uac

Here are picture of the screen take with a external camera (since screenshot is disabled by default for UAC for security reasons, but this is not important at all), here are two pictures of the exact same window in case you can't see the full window. [image: picture 1], [image: picture 2.].

Note: In the pictures there is not shown that there are two users to choose from, me and another. I think the other is the one that came with the computer by default, and Pedro is me the one who created the profile "pedro". I haven't tried with the other user actually, I will try. But normally my user has had no problems like this with other UAC before, so it doesn't make sense, also my user has root.

This is a recurrent UAC, it appears every 5 minutes (!!!) driving me insane. I put the correct password giving administrative rights to the program, but still, five minutes later, needs authorization again. I tried accepting and refusing, also I 100% sure the password I insert when accepting is correct. How to stop this nonsense? My pc is Lenovo with Windows 10.

Edit: In response to a helpful request, [more pictures when I click show details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sPEJ.jpg) When clicking show certificate, it shows a valid certificate, it doesn't matter too see it.

Comment: What happens when you click "show more details"?

Comment: "I don't know what it is, but it keeps popping up, so I figured I'd hit OK and allow it to run".  YIKES.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I actually, not explained here, but have confidence is trustable. This computer has asian software. And this UAC has cryptographic certificates verified. Do you think this is unsafe?

Comment: [How to Remove Baidu Hijacker on Internet Explorer](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-remove-baidu-hijacker-on-internet-explorer). In general, if you don't know what it is, or why it's asking for permission to change things, you shouldn't trust it, regardless of the fact that it may or may not have a valid certificate attached.

Comment: @DavidPostill I answered you! Thanks for contributing.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks! That is good advice. I'm very careful, it was dumb to accept, but, it came in a very believable package, and the certificates seem to be from my own pc. It seems a non-virus software, but is annoying.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 IMHO What you found is not the program I;'m getting notifications for, it's another thing. Baidu is a big company. Thanks!

Comment: @Santropedro Now you know where it is located. You can kill any Baidu processes and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved when I simply went to uninstall programs in Windows 10 control panel and unistalled that seemed "baidu something" it was mostly in chinese so I don't know even how it's called.